# Popcorn.js and jQuery

Tags: jquery, popcornjs

Is there a way to target Popcorn.js elements using jQuery.
Example: I have this below as a method with a div in the text area. I am adding a close span to attempt to close the parent div if the person does not want to wait the 8 seconds until the element closes. This is in my script.js

```
example.popupFootnote({ "id": "footnote",
    "start": 2,
    "end": 10,
    "target": "footnotes",
    "title": "Tear Gas",
    "text": '<div id="exampleBox"><span style="float:right; margin-right:10px">Close Window</span><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tear_gas">Tear gas</a>, formally known as a lachrymatory agent or lachrymator (from lacrima meaning "a tear" in Latin), is a non-lethal chemical compound that stimulates the corneal nerves in the eyes to cause tearing, pain, and even blindness. Common lachrymators include OC, CS, CR, CN, nonivamide, bromoacetone, phenacyl bromide, xylyl bromide and syn-propanethial-S-oxide (from onions). Lacrymators often share the structural element Z=C-C-X, where Z indicates carbon or oxygen, and X indicates bromide or chloride.</div>',
    top: '10%',
    left: '70%'
});`
```

So I wan't it when the element 'closeWindow' is clicked then the box its parent closes.

this is in my index.html below my script.js in the HTML between script tags.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#closeWindow').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });

});
```

The HTML elements are laid out like this:

```
<div id="movieHolder">

<div id="video" style="width: 750px; height: 422px;" ></div>

    <div id="overlayDiv"></div>

    <div id="overlayDiv-Map"></div>

    <div id="footnotes"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Event Delegation or the new [jQuery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler method to do this, here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bcmoney/PTJ4w/
(scrub to 25 seconds for the popcorn footnote to popup)

You were pretty close but forgot to actually put:

```
<span id="closeWindow" style="float:right; margin-right:10px">Close Window</span>
```

Also, might want to move inline CSS to an external stylesheet or at least the header but I'm sure you know that.

Lastly, the jQuery would be changed to the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#closeWindow').live("click", function () {
          $(this).parent().parent().hide();
      });
  });
```

Comment: +1. Note, you don't need to put this in a `$(document).ready()` call since it's a live event.

Comment: Just an FYI, `.live()` isn't really "new" and, in fact, has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 in favor of `.on()`

Comment: That was it thank you for the support. I have not dealt much with .live or the .on functionality. I appreciate it immensely.

Comment: Yes, I see that now... Hard to keep up with jQuery, consulting a book is obviously much less effective than checking the latest API docs. When I said "new" I was actually thinking of  .delegate()  which was introduced in 1.4.3 almost a yr ago to the day so its fairly new in world history sense but maybe ancient history in web years. Meanwhile its  .live()  counterpart still had newness to me but admittedly not that new, new enough to not had run into any quirks with it yet though. Make it:

      $('#closeWindow').on("click", function () {
          $(this).parent().parent().hide();
      });