# Using jQuery Functions to trigger Popcorn.JS Events

Tags: jquery, interactive, popcornjs

I'm attempting to create a Choose Your Own Adventure interactive video, and I'm trying to find a way to integrate Popcorn.JS and jQuery. I've already read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127794/popcorn-js-and-jquery) about Popcorn/jQuery interaction (which is why I'm using the .on function in the code) but it was different than what I'm looking to to.

I want to try to have Popcorn.JS elements be triggered by jQuery actions (e.g. when the user clicks inside a certain div the video will skip to 36 seconds and begin playing) as well as having jQuery functions be triggered by certain times in the video (e.g. when the video reaches 20 seconds it triggers jQuery to fadeOut a specific div).

*For this one, the video pauses at 12 seconds, and then I'm trying to find a way so that when the user clicks in #BoxToBeClicked, the video will go to 30 seconds and begin playing from there.*

```
    var pop = Popcorn('#demo_video', {
        pauseOnLinkClicked: true
    });

    pop.play();

    pop.cue(12, function(){
        pop.pause();
    });

    $('#BoxToBeClicked').on("click", function(){
        $('#demo_video').currentTime(30).play();
    });
```

*For this one, I'm trying to find a way to have a div fade out whenever the video reaches 46 seconds*

```
    pop.cue(46, function() {
        $('#Fader').on("fadeOut('slowly')");
    });
```